# Text align in different parts of a text in a Dialog

Tags: java, android, dialog

I have text that I show in a Dialog, and let's say I want to right align, left align or center it. That works for me if I want to align the whole text. But what can I do if I want to align different parts of the text, for example the first line to be right aligned and the next one left aligned?

This is what I have now, here I align it to the right.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.dialog_2_options);
    setCancelable(false);


    mMessageView = findViewById(R.id.read_message);
    btnOption1 = findViewById(R.id.btn_option1);
    btnOption2 = findViewById(R.id.btn_option2);
  
    btnOption1.setText(sbOption1.toString());
    btnOption2.setText(sbOption2.toString());
    mMessageView.setText(sbMessage.toString());
    mMessageView.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the `TextView` widget does not allow that. The easiest way would be to use multiple `TextView`s and to align each in the way you want.

In your dialog_2_options layout, you can use multiple `TextView`s (below each other) and then you can set their gravity in the xml layout file or programatically as you do in your snippet if you want to change the alignment dynamically.

If you want to have single lines, you can limit each TextView with `android:maxLines=1`